# VLOOKUP links in openpyxl generated spreadsheet breaking when moved

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlwings

I have a Python Openpyxl tool that populates a spreadsheet from a database and then creates individual spreadsheet forms for each row with Vlookup links based on the name field so the master spreadsheet can be edited and the individual spreadsheets will update automatically. The links all work fine the problem is the end users of the tool want to be able to move the parent folder around after the sheets are generated, and moving the folder breaks the data links, even though the master is in a subfolder of the individual spreadsheet location. If all 50+ individual sheets are opened manually and saved so the relative path is stored in the XML they can be moved, but I am wondering if there is any easier automatic way. I tried using xlwings as well after saving with openpyxl just to open, save, and close the file but it still won't save the relative path unless done manually. is this just a limitation I have to live with? Any advice is appreciated.

```
def split_stakesheet(stakesheet, stakesheet_wb, stake_dict, inputs, current_date):
    stake_dir = os.path.join(inputs['output_location'], 'STAKESHEETS')
    if not os.path.exists(stake_dir):
        os.mkdir(stake_dir)
    if stake_dict is None:
        stake_dict = {}
        for index, column in enumerate(stakesheet_wb.columns):
            if column[3].value in ['LAT.', 'LONG.', 'X', 'Y'] and index > 15:
                stake_dict[column[3].value + ' NAD 83'] = index
            stake_dict[column[3].value] = index
    lookup = '=VLOOKUP("{}", \'{}STAKESHEET\'!A:AJ, {}, FALSE)'

    individual_ss = load_workbook(filename=inputs['individual_ss'])

    for index, row in enumerate(stakesheet_wb.rows):
        if index < 4:
            pass
        elif row[0].value is None:
            break
        else:
            logo = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('LOGO.png')
            p2e = pixels_to_EMU
            logo.height = 50
            logo.width = 50
            position = XDRPoint2D(p2e(425), p2e(28))

            size = XDRPositiveSize2D(p2e(logo.width), p2e(logo.height))

            logo.anchor = AbsoluteAnchor(pos=position, ext=size)
            name = row[0].value


            new_ws = individual_ss.active
            new_ws.title = name.split(" ")[-1]
            new_ws.add_image(logo)

            for jindex, line in enumerate(new_ws):
                if jindex < 3:
                    pass
                elif jindex == 4:
                    line[1].value = name
                elif jindex in COORDS:
                    line[1].value = row[stake_dict[COORDS[jindex]]].value
                elif jindex in VLOOKUP:
                    line[1].value = lookup.format(name, os.path.join(inputs['output_location'], "STAKESHEETS", 'MASTER', '[STAKESHEET_{}.xlsx]'.format(current_date)), row[stake_dict[VLOOKUP[jindex]]].column)

            individual_ss.save(os.path.join(stake_dir, '{}.xlsx'.format(name)))
            with xlwings.App(visible=False) as app:
                wb = xlwings.Book(os.path.join(stake_dir, '{}.xlsx'.format(name)))
                wb.save(os.path.join(stake_dir, '{}.xlsx'.format(name)))
                wb.close()
```